# The push notification is sent successfully using firebase FCM token but I don't get it in my Device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notifications to a user using Firebase cloud messaging. I take the user token from a user and send the notification but I'm not able to get the notification. I get the API response that shows the notification is sent successfully. On my device, I don't get any notifications

Now what I can do now?

my Push Notification service is:

```
public class FirebasePushNotification
             extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private String CHANNEL_ID = "104";
    private int notificationId = 107;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage removeMassage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(removeMassage);

        System.out.println(removeMassage.getFrom());

        Map<String, String> data = removeMassage.getData();
        String title = data.get("title");
        String message = data.get("message");

        System.out.println(data);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo_new)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
    }
    
}
```

There I have created a override method that will receive the notification. I don't understand is there any wrong?

my Push notification send method is:

```
public void sendNotification(String fcmToken, String title, String body) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("to", fcmToken);

            JSONObject notificationData = new JSONObject();
            notificationData.put("title", title);
            notificationData.put("body", body);

            jsonBody.put("notification", notificationData);

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            // Notification sent successfully
                            System.out.println(response.toString());
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // Handle error
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    headers.put("Authorization", "key=***********************");
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            queue.add(request);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have used the Vollay library to call the API. I think there is no problem because the response is always showing the notification is successful.

The response is:

```
{"multicast_id":819200533774759281,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1688929068591057%f384335af384335a"}]}
```

so that there is no problem.

My manifest is:

```
 <service
            android:name=".FirebasePushNotification"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MASSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I have also tried com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID but that is not work. Is there any issue?

this is the function that I am using to send notification to a user:

```
PushNotificationExtra notificationExtra = new PushNotificationExtra(getContext());
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                    String token = task.getResult();
                    notificationExtra.sendNotification(token, "Test", "body");
                }
            });
           
        });
```

what can I do about this problem? how to solve it?
this is an android app which is written in java

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest file, the action name should be MESSAGING_EVENT, not MASSAGING_EVENT.

```
    <service
        android:name="FirebasePushNotification"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```